# Neutrino field is left-handed

Tags: particle-physics, mass, neutrinos, chirality

Why if we take the mass of neutrino to be zero then we get only left-handed field when $\psi_r=\frac{1}{2}(1+\gamma^5)\psi$ and $\psi_l=\frac{1}{2}(1-\gamma^5)\psi$ has no dependence on mass?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer comes out the Lagrangian of the standard model. In this Lagrangian the neutrinos (or any other lepton) appears in (at most) two places:

The dynamic term: this is a cuadratic term on the (covariant) derivative of the field. Every field has a dynamic term.

The mass term: this is a Yukawa interaction of the field with the Higgs field. Not every field has a mass term (for example the photon does not).

It turns out that only left handed components appear in the dynamic term however in the mass term both left handed and right handed components appear.

So if the neutrino have no mass (i.e. the Yukawa coupling is cero), there is no mass term and therefore there is no right handed neutrino in the lagrangian. This might not be a satisfactory answer since it only reflects the math behind but the physical question stills open. To my understanding there is no explanation...we know from experiments that parity violation occurs and that in fact it is maximal and we therefore build our theoretical models to describe that reality. As far as I know there is no good explanation of why parity violation occurs at all.